# Strange behavior using variable in Exists

Tags: equation-solving, variable

I came across a behavior that doesn't make sense to me when I tried to use Exists in Reduce.

If I run commands:

```
l = {a0, a1, x};
Reduce[Exists[l , a1 != 0 && a0 + a1 x == 0 && a1 < 0], Reals]
```

I get output:

```
a1 < 0 && a0 == -a1 x
```

But if I run command:

```
Reduce[Exists[{a0, a1, x} , a1 != 0 && a0 + a1 x == 0 && a1 < 0], Reals]
```

I get output:

```
True
```

I think the problem is in exists part:

```
Exists[l, a1 != 0 && a0 + a1 x == 0 && a1 < 0]
```

Gives output

```
a1 != 0 && a0 + a1 x == 0 && a1 < 0
```

And

```
Exists[{a0, a1, x} , a1 != 0 && a0 + a1 x == 0 && a1 < 0]
```

Gives output (which I think is correct):

```
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Exists]\), \({a0, a1, x}\)]\((a1 != 0 && a0 + a1\ x == 0 && a1 < 0)\)\)
```

Can somebody explain what is going on there and how could I use variable in Exists if this not the correct way?

Comment: probably related to the holding attribute. Compare `Reduce[Exists[Evaluate@l, a1 != 0 && a0 + a1 x == 0 && a1 < 0]]` with `Reduce[Exists[l, a1 != 0 && a0 + a1 x == 0 && a1 < 0]]`

Comment: @belisarius You reply or Community Wiki or something? ;o) Soon I will need to save that quote.

Comment: @Öskå :) It is just a hunch. I don't have time right now to investigate further. Be my guest to post an answer ... or something :)

Comment: @belisarius What you suggested made it work. Thank you very much.I don't think it is related to Hold though. Shouldn't ´ReleaseHold[l]´ have to also work in that case (which it didn't)?

Comment: @user1335014 If what belisarius proposed you fixed your issue please answer your own question :)

Answer (score 2):

As belisarius pointed out the strange behavior disappears when using `Evaluate`.

```
Reduce[Exists[Evaluate[l] , a1 != 0 && a0 + a1 x == 0 && a1 < 0], Reals]
```

Gives output:

```
True
```